Computing the order of eigenvectors based off of the magnitude of the corresponding eigenvalues when $N$ is moderately large
Let's say we have an $N$x$N$ matrix $M$ with entries in $\mathbb Z_2$. If we compute the eigenvalues of $M$, we run into an issue where an eigenvalue could easily be of magnitude $10^{-100}$ when $N=30$ or especially when $N=200+$. Eventually, the numerical precision won't preserve the ordering on the magnitude between eigenvalues, mapping two unequal but miniscule magnitude eigenvalues to 0.0, forgetting the ordering between the two elements.
So, is there a way, without specifically computing the eigenvalues, as they can be too small as $N$ grows moderately large, to order the unit eigenvectors by eigenvalues in increasing order? As in, compute the order of eigenvectors based on true eigenvalue magnitude, without necessarily being able to compute the eigenvalues to an arbitrary number of digits, since typical eigenvalue libraries will return a number taking only so many bits of information, and cannot represent arbitrary floating point numbers.

Do you have any estimate of the largest eigenvalue or condition number of $M$? That will be the factor that determines if this is feasible or not.

@whpowell96 The smallest eigenvalue of a $N$x$N$ matrix with entries in ${0,1}$ is asymptotic to $n^{-n/2(1+o(1))}$. So these eigenvalues can get extremely small as I said even when $N$ is moderately large, say $N=200$.

So it isn't possible to determine, for two eigenvectors, which one has a smaller magnitude eigenvalue, without specifically computing the $k$-th digit of each eigenvalue until the $k$-th digit proves that one is smaller than the other? That's really disappointing, but I can live with this reality and dig deeper into calculating $k$-th digits of eigenvalues.

Almost every eigenvalue algorithm is negatively impacted by the magnitude of the condition number $\kappa_2(M) = \frac{\sigma_1(M)}{\sigma_N(M)}$. Once can show that $\sigma_N(M) < \min |\lambda(M)|$ so extremely small eigenvalues can make algorithms unstable. The matrix you describe will be considered singular by basically any algorithm.

@whpowell96 I understand that, but might it be possible to compare two eigenvectors directly to see which one must have larger eigenvalue, without necessarily computing either to a high degree of accuracy.. I suppose not, no worries.
